# ListPicker text obscured by other text on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, toolkit

I am using the ListPicker from the Windows Phone Toolkit.  It is setup very basically, but for some reason, the items in the popup are always obscured by anything below them, like this:

[image]

Here, the text “jburchel” was beneath the ListPicker, and _http://science.nasa.gov/me  Was a ListPickerItem.  You can see how the underlying text box appears normally but the ListPickerItem is below.  I tried changing the order on the XAML of the ListPicker and TextBlock, but it didn't help.  I have tried lots of combinations of settings, messed around with the template, but this has persisted.  Does anybody know this problem?

Here is an example of ListPicker XAML I use.  It is extremely basic.

```
           <toolkit:ListPicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,41,0,0" Name="txtUrl" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="434" Cursor="IBeam">
            <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="http://rss.cnn.com/services/podcasting/studentnews/rss"/>
            <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="http://science.nasa.gov/media/medialibrary/2010/10/28/podcast.xml"/>
            <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="http://www.sciencemag.org/rss/podcast.xml"/>
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="33,19,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="Podcast URL:" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBox Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,141,0,0" Name="txtUser" Text="jburchel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be (though can't say for sure without more XAML) that you're laying out your controls using the **Margin** to position elements. As you've just found out, this isn't necesarily the best approach to take. Silverlight has a wide range of layout containers that help you lay out your controls without requiring you to manually position each element.

In this instance, it seems that you might be positioning controls vertically stacked above each other, for which you can use the `StackPanel` container. You simply add each child element to the `StackPanel` and it handles layout them out on top of each other. Once you've done this, because the next element is always below the `ListPicker`, when the `ListPicker` expands, the elements below it are pushed down.

For more complex layouts you can use the `Grid` container (which is almost certainly the current parent container of your controls), but you should use rows and columns to ensure that elements don't "bleed" into each other. Note: The flexibility of the `Grid` element comes at a price and you shoudl carefully consider whether you need to use it or whether you can use a simpler container, especially for repeated containers in lists, for example.

If you're new to the layout system in Silverlight, you may find this resource particularly useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645025(VS.95).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I think this is almost the answer I need, but now, although the original behavior no longer occurs, the expansion of the ListPicker forces all elements down below it.  I was hoping for a nice layered effect where the UI pops up and just covers elements below it.  Maybe I am expecting too much for a phone UI?  Or is there some easy way to do this?

Comment: If you want the `ListPicker` to appear over the other items in the page like a combo box, then you need to ensure that you set a non-transparent colour for the **Background** property. Your screenshot shows a white background, so presumably you're using the device themes, in which case you should use `Background="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a transparent background for your list picker.

Comment: Thanks.  But my background is not transparent.  In fact, the item that appears transparent is the item BEHIND the picker, and the picker appears to be beneath it...  I will play with these settings more though and if this does turn out to be related, will vote yours as an answer too.  Thank you again.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and just figured it out. It is the order that you define the elements in the xaml file that matters. The one that comes first are rendered first and therefore will go underneath the rest. In your case, this should solve the problem:

Comment: Copy and paste the <TextBlock> element before the <toolkit:listPicker>.

Answer (score 0):

ListPicker and following controls should be in a stackpannel:

```
<StackPanel Margin="0,144,0,51" DataContext="{Binding}">
   <toolkit:ListPicker Margin="10,0" Header="Service Executive" SelectedIndex="0">
      <ListBoxItem Content="Eva" Height="34" Width="444"/>
      <ListBoxItem Content="Ramon"/>
      <ListBoxItem Content="Santi"/>
      <ListBoxItem Content="David"/>
      <ListBoxItem Content="Alberto"/>
      <ListBoxItem Content="Jaime"/>
      <ListBoxItem Content="Jacinto"/>
   </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you can just change the ZIndex to something higher (how higher the ZIndex the more your controls are on front). I changed it to 100;

In **blend**:

### [image: Adjusting Z index in blend]

In **xaml**:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker
    Canvas.ZIndex="100" />
```

This way you can keep your order of items in xaml without obscuring items